# How to receive multipart files using Slim framework from android client?

Tags: android, slim

I sent image file and content (text) using retrofit from android client and tried to get them in the server side but can not do that and the error is always : it is null.
Please how can I send image and receive it using #Retrofit and Slim framework?
If anyone can help, I will appreciate.

..............................................
Tried to send the image from android client like a multipart file and receive it with slim using method (getUploadedFiles) and it didn't work.

```
 @Multipart
    @POST("createPostWithImage")
    Call<DefaultResponse> uploadTestPost(
            @Part("desc") RequestBody desc,
            @Part MultipartBody.Part image
    );
```

```
$app-> post('/createPostWithImage', function(Request $request, Response $response) {

    $directory = __DIR__.'../photos/1';
    $uploadedFiles = $request->getUploadedFiles();
    $uploadedFile = $uploadedFiles['photo'];
    $uploadedFile->moveTo($directory);


});
```

get the file which was sent from android client and save it into specific folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$app->post('/file', function($request,$response) {
try{
     $directory = $this->get('upload_directory');
     $uploadedFiles = $request->getUploadedFiles();
     $uploadedFile = $uploadedFiles['example1'];
     $extension = pathinfo($uploadedFile->getClientFilename(), PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $basename =  mt_rand(10000000, 99999999);
    $uploadedFile->moveTo($directory . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $basename.'.'.$extension);
return $response->withJson(array('message' =>$uploadedFile),200);
}
catch(\Exception $ex){
       return $response->withJson(array('error' => $ex->getMessage()),422);
}
});    


//minimal code to get started ...
```